# Border-image gradient pattern in triangle shape

Tags: css, border, css-shapes, border-image, css-gradients

I want to create an odd shaped triangle with css. My first thought was to use transparent borders with `transform: rotate` and it worked (see left triangle). Now I want to use a gradient border image pattern as background for a same triangle but I can't make it work. I tried many things like changing `border-width`, using wrappers and `overflow:hidden` among others, nothing worked. Here I post one of my tries (see right shape) as you see the pattern takes all the space, not following the triangle shape. Any ideas?

```css
#top-left {
  position:absolute;
  left:78px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;  
  border-right: 80px solid black;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}

#top-right {
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, pink, pink 1%, purple 1%, purple 8%) 10;
  border-image-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="top-left"></div>  
 <div id="top-right"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Andrey Fedorov's answer is good, but there is a problem when the background is not a solid color, like this for example:

```css
body{  
background-color: #6d695c;
background-image:
repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1)),
linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1));
background-size: 70px 120px;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#top-left {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid #fff;  
 border-right: 80px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}

#top-right {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, pink, pink 1%, purple 1%, purple 8%) 10;
  border-image-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="top-left"></div>  
 <div id="top-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use `linear-gradient` with `no-repeat` and `background-size` to draw each pieces :

examples by steps from a single tag :

```css
/* testing gradients */
p , div#wrapper {
  width:80px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  height:150px;
  /* see me then remove this  shadow */
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px;
}
p {
  background:
    linear-gradient(130deg, transparent 49.75%, pink 50.5%) 0 42px  no-repeat ;
  background-size:
    100% 15px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}
p + p{
  background:
    linear-gradient(130deg, transparent 49.75%, pink 50.5%) 0 42px  no-repeat ,
    linear-gradient(130deg,transparent 62px, purple 63px) top no-repeat;
  background-size:
    100% 15px,
    100% 65%;
}
p + p + p {
  
  background:
    linear-gradient(130deg, transparent 49.75%, pink 50.5%) 0 42px  no-repeat ,
    linear-gradient(130deg,transparent 62px, purple 63px) top no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(33deg , transparent 42px, pink 43px) no-repeat bottom;
  background-size:
    100% 15px,
    100% 65%, 
    100% 8px;
}
p+ p + p + p {
    background:
    linear-gradient(130deg, transparent 49.75%, pink 50.5%) 0 42px  no-repeat ,
    linear-gradient(130deg,transparent 62px, purple 63px) top no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(33deg , transparent 42px, pink 43px) no-repeat bottom, 
    linear-gradient(33deg, transparent 42px, purple 43px) bottom no-repeat;
  background-size:
    100% 15px,
    100% 65%, 
    100% 8px, 
    100% 35.5%;
  }
p:last-of-type{
  box-shadow:0 0
}

/* your original CSS/issue */
body{  
background-color: #6d695c;
background-image:
repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1)),
linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1));
background-size: 70px 120px;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#top-left {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid #fff;  
 border-right: 80px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
  transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}

#top-right {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, pink, pink 1%, purple 1%, purple 8%) 10;
  border-image-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
  transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}
```

```html
<!-- your issue -->
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="top-left"></div>  
 <div id="top-right"></div>
</div>
<!-- p for testing purpose -->
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

inbricated element + gradient & transform could do too:

```css
body{  
background-color: #6d695c;
background-image:
repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1)),
linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1));
background-size: 70px 120px;
}

div.inbricate {
  margin:1em;
  height:150px;
  width:80px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform:rotate(-20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 ;
}
.inbricate div {
  transform:rotate(31deg) scale(1.2, 0.9) skew(-5deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 102%;
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(-40deg,   pink 8%, purple 8%, purple 65%, pink 65%, pink 75%, purple 75% )
}
```

```html
<div class=inbricate>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @8odoros Yep, This is the idea, you can also inbricate elements and use transform : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OXEqog

Comment: I certainly keep this, it is calculations-heavy though...not your fault, but one of my main goals is changing the patterns through a UI.

Comment: then i guess a repeating-gradient and an inbricated div +  transform should do better , else, SVG would be great too

Comment: One last issue, I can't find a solution...your last example is almost perfect but when using the same pattern the inbricated div has its background transformed. How can I reset this? Check this http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/AXgLWG

Comment: @8odoros not sure i understand the use of it. if background are the same, then let it transparent, else to have both background to match will be very difficult 1) first is to match background-position 2) second , since it is rescaled, background is too. 3) begin of solution: use a third  inbricated div, reverse rotate and scale , then look for a way to match background position (background-attachment fixed is an easy hint for both bg ).

Comment: added borders to see it if you wanna play http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLAroa , i'll be offline a few hours

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is this:

- Put both shapes in the same place.
- Using `z-index` make the one with the pattern go behind the other
- Use white (or whatever color is the shape background) to paint the border area outside the triangle.
- Make transparent the border that had the triangle color

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  }

#top-left {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid #fff;  
 border-right: 80px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}

#top-right {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, pink, pink 1%, purple 1%, purple 8%) 10;
  border-image-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-width: 100px 80px 50px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="top-left"></div>  
 <div id="top-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What? That's magic! Let me study that awesomeness a bit before I upvote ;-) just a minor issue (in Chrome at least) there is a ultra slim border visible around the triangle's box.

Comment: this artefacts linear-gradient in a chrome (

Comment: Just a note of caution, placing a white colored layer on top wouldn't exactly be the same as what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: sure, but otherwise you need to completely change the approach

Comment: Cool trick, although it does have its drawbacks, that white colored border has top be changed according to the background color. I'll wait a bit in case anyone proposes a better one before I accept.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should make a mention so as to set the expectations straight with all users who are going to see this answer in future. Just a suggestion.